# Chrome Extension: Simulating focus on non-focused tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm currently building a chrome extension that within its functionality, it opens from the **popup** links in new tabs. Within those new tabs, there's a content that should be loaded. The problem is that the content is only loaded as a trigger to when the page is scrolled down to the bottom *and* when the page is triggered. My main question is how can I make the content to get loaded? can I?

My **content script** automatically scrolls down to the bottom of the document when its loaded, but how can I simulate the page focus? I guess I can just simulate the content loading but as for this moment it looks like the more cumbersome way.

So if there's some way to simulate a tab focus using the **content script**, i'll be happy to here about that!

Comment: I think this is a job for [background scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) not content scripts because backgrounds scripts listen for events - like events happening on the tab. You can also check if the new tab is currently ["loading" or "complete"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6642243/6577242) and based on that you can execute a code/script .

Answer (score 0):

You can focus on any tab and make it active tab using below code:

```
var updateProperties = {"active": true};
var tabId = 123;
chrome.tabs.update(tabId, updateProperties, function(tab){ });
```

Don't forget to get the correct tab id and assign it to `tabId`